# Existence of extensions of a flat projective morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $S$ is a noetherian integral scheme and $U\subset S$ is an open subscheme.  Let $f:X\to U$ be a flat projective morphism.  I would like to know whether (or when) $f$ can be extended to a flat projective morphism $g:Y\to S$.

Comment: Projectivity of connected components of Hilbert scheme.  Well, only for codimension 1.

Comment: A necessary condition: extensibility of $f_*(O_X)$.